# Akka: do I understand Akka actor ideology right?

Tags: akka

I do have a task, when system initiates bunch of individual requests to an external system. For simplicity let's assume we have a text and to goal is to calculate number of letters in the text.

I would suggest following design:

> TextProcessor - processes whole text
>
> WordProcessor - processes any particular word

But now is the question: is *WordProcessor* a singleton (disruptor) which processes words in sequential manner or is it a *unit of work* and multiple *WordProcessor*s run in a parallel?

Comment: It's really hard to say what you are asking here. What is the relation between `TextProcessor` and `WordProcessor`? How do they communicate among themselves and with the outside world? Why does the task have to "initiate a bunch of requests" - is it for better parallelism, something else? Please enhance your question so that it paints a clearer picture of the situation at hand.

Comment: Well, if I understand you correctly, both TextProcessor and WordProcessor are represented as actors in Akka. TextProcessor actor spawns and delivers work to WordProcessor actors (potentially many of them, in parallel). So, the *is it a unit of work and multiple WordProcessors run in a parallel* part you mentioned fits very good with the actor model IMHO.